# drawing ellipse with rotation cause inaccurate result

Tags: graphics, 2d, drawing, draw, ellipse

i'am a junior in computer graphics , currently i learn how to draw ellipses with rotation .

when i preform rotation with 90deg or 180deg nothing unusual happened , but when i try to rotate with any other value the result will be like this :

[image]

i tried rotation and shearing , both of them lead to same problem "inaccurate result" .